# Bash logging including line number

Tags: bash, logging

I am used to `SLF4J` in Java and `logging` in Python where I can have function names *and* **line numbers** as fields of my output format.

Emphasis on: **line number**

Can I get a similar thing in Bash?

Objective: build a `log_error` generic function to call from my (huge) script, outputting severity level of error source, function name and line number.

Intended usage:

```
log_error "INFO: my info" ... # called from within my_function at line 20
```

Intended output:

```
[INFO] my_function@20 my info
```

Is such a thing possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$LINENO](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/lineno.htm): Each time this parameter is referenced, the shell substitutes a decimal number representing the current sequential line number (starting with 1) within a script or function.

Answer (score 3):

Hope below example with `shopt -s expand_aliases` and `alias` could help:

**try.sh**

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s expand_aliases

# =============================================================
# Define the logger
# =============================================================
alias logger='logger_function [${BASH_SOURCE##*/}] [$FUNCNAME] [$LINENO] '

logger_function()
{
    echo $@
}

# =============================================================
# Use the logger
# =============================================================
my_function()
{
    logger "hello world!"
}

my_function
```

**Test result in: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release**

```
$ ./try.sh
[try.sh] [my_function] [20] hello world!
```

Considering the question is emphasizing on: **line number**, so in this example, the exactly same input and output of the question are not used.

But to make it more informative, the logging utility definition is added with:

- `$BASH_SOURCE`
- `$FUNCNAME`
- `$LINENO`

So, it can print the file name, function name and line number.

Regarding to `alias` usage here, it looks like but isn't really comparable to a C macro according to: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using the `BASH_LINENO` array.  Here is the extract from [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

> BASH_LINENO
>   An array variable whose members are the line numbers in
>   source files where each corresponding member of FUNCNAME was invoked.
>   ${BASH_LINENO[$i]} is the line number in the source file
>   (${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}) where ${FUNCNAME[$i]} was called (or
>   ${BASH_LINENO[$i-1]} if referenced within another shell function). Use
>   LINENO to obtain the current line number.

Here is a comprehensive logging implementation for Bash:

https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/stdlib.sh

Comment: Great, thanks. So `"${BASH_SOURCE[1]}${BASH_LINENO[0]}"` means "parent source file and line number".